# phrases for showing to be victimized

Tags: phrase-request

I wrote:

> There is a policy in the current government **to show itself victimized** by suggesting some men who won't pass the Gaurdian Council's filter.

It's the literal translation of a quote by a conservative man about the presidential policy of the current president of Iran for the next round.

What is the related phrases for "to show be victimized" to grab attention or support? I mean a deliberate move by someone to show themselves oppressed...

Comment: aggrieved? https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aggrieved

Comment: @miltonaut the defination 2.b may works. It's more the act or a policy to pretend being aggrieved.